# iOS how does NSMutableArray check if it contains NSNumber objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm writing some code that will be using NSMutableArray and storing int values within it, wrapped within NSNumbers.

**I would like to confirm that querying an iOS NSArray or NSMutableArray using new NSNumbers with same values is legal**, of if I need to explicitly iterate over the array, and check if each int value is equal to the value I want to test against?

This appears to work:

```
NSMutableArray* walkableTiles = [NSMutableArray array];    


[walkableTiles addObject:@(1)];
[walkableTiles addObject:@(2)];
[walkableTiles addObject:@(3)];


if([walkableTiles containsObject:@(1)])
{
    DLog(@"contains 1"); //test passes
}
if([walkableTiles containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0]])
{
    DLog(@"contains 2");//test passes
}
if([walkableTiles containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]])
{
    DLog(@"contains 3");//test passes
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *legal*? I'm pretty sure that `containsObject:` iterates over the array at some point.

Comment: Have you read the spec for containsObject? "This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by sending an isEqual: message to each of the array’s objects (and passing anObject as the parameter to each isEqual: message)."

Comment: Instead of NSNumber numberWithint: you can use literals and use @(3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. Why wouldn't it be?

The `containsObject:` method actually iterates over the array and calls the `isEqual:` method on each object passing in the object you are checking for.

BTW - there is nothing special here about using `NSNumber`. It's the same with an array of any object type. As long as the object's class has a valid `isEqual:` method, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Apple's NSNumber documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/isEqualToNumber%3a), you should use `isEqualToNumber`:

> isEqualToNumber: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the
>   receiver and a given number are equal.
>   - (BOOL)isEqualToNumber:(NSNumber *)aNumber

Comment: But isEqual will work just fine.  It simply isn't as tightly typed.

Comment: (NSNumber conforms to NSObject, where isEqual is defined.)